# Fastest way to output a 2D array of char in C

Tags: c, performance, io

I'm just working on a snake game project, but I just realized that the old `printf` is too slow to display a 15*45 2-dimensional array.

If you know any I/O to output it faster please help me!

My goal is about 0.10 - 0.15 s.

I accept libraries too but I want full copyright :p :p.

```
for (y = 0; y < MAX_Y ; y++) 
 {
  printf ("\t");
  for (x = 0; x < MAX_X; x++)
   {
    printf ("%c", base[y][x]);  
   }
  printf ("\n");
 }
```

Comment: printf() is "slow". you'd be better off building one longer string out of your individual characters and outputting the big string ONCE, rather than outputting each individual character.

Comment: You can try to only print the part of array that has changed, instead of print the whole array every time you want to update the screen.

Comment: No Szoke, asking for help and stating you want full copyright in the same question...? Anyway..... learn opengl, or directx (Google them). Or buy an i7 based PC..... and using the console for output... budget for an income of zero. But seriously, google OpenGL.... it's for displaying graphics.

Comment: I tried that but the prgogram gets comfused whit spaces when I compile.       Lol Gavin that was a joke :p and i can program only C

Comment: `printf` is as old as `for`(at least in C)...

Comment: Actually I think printf is very fast compared to the actual output. I noticed that a simple program under cygwin (compiled with gcc 4.8.3) was running 10 times as long in a DOS command window than in a mintty window (not X but a windows adaption). Whether that is a cygwin artefact or just some cmd window slowness I don't know, but the actual printf without any conversion (%c for god's sake!) should be done in a few microseconds. The function call is the most expensive part, I guess. Even in the DOS window I could print a matrix in 2ms (roughly 4s for 2000 prints). How long does yours take?

Comment: You may already be optimizing, but if not try compiling with `-O3` or `-Ofast` to let the compilier attempt to optimize the output to the greatest extent. The only other option is to write a quick `assembly` function to write the needed characters out -- you will have function call overhead either way (`printf`, `putchar`, or `yourAssemblyFunc`), you may be able to shave a significant percentage either way. (although `printf`, etc. should be well optimized)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Well, putchar is often a macro anyway, thus no overhead there. Other functions may be inlined with higher optimizations. But I tried: putchar is not any faster. I think that as soon as I/O is concerned the CPU load pales.

Comment: You're wrong, think about what `printf` must do that `putchar` don't need to. Next, `printf` and `putchar` are user lib functions and use user-space buffering, so they consume almost CPU. This is the idea behind such functions: use memory access in place of real I/O on devices.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm not sure what you exactly meant ("consume almost CPU"?) but my reasoning was that yes, the actual computations printf proper does may need 0.02 microseconds per char while putchar needs only 0.01 but then both write to a locked buffer which is read by some device driver that talks to some periphery which waits for an interrupt and then writes to a buffer where device emulation reads the data and looks up a glyph according to the tty settings ... you get the idea. That putchar is faster in your case is interesting. Is that user time you are reporting ("u")?

Comment: No `printf` and `putchar` works almost all the time with a buffer in user-space (this involves only CPU). That buffer is of course sometimes written to the device, but even in this case, this involves calling a system function (`write` under Unixes) which in turn only write to a buffer in system-space! System calls are slow but mainly because they verify validity of their arguments before really running. The real I/O is done behind the scene asynchronously.

Comment: Yes `u` is for user time, because `s` which is system-time is not relevant here. For your info, I got : 0.001s or 0.000s whatever the function I used.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks whit Mingw @PeterSchneider is this good enough or if not where do i find a better compiler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't use real formatting, and print only individual chars you can use the simple `putchar()` function:

```
for (y = 0; y < MAX_Y ; y++) 
 {
  putchar ('\t');
  for (x = 0; x < MAX_X; x++)
   {
    putchar(base[y][x]);  
   }
  putchar('\n');
 }
```

On my machine, iterating the loops 100,000, testing it in 3 runs and redirecting output to `/dev/null`, gave me:

- 6.679u, 6.663u and 6.766u with `printf`,
- 3.309u, 3.315u and 3.312u with `putchar`,
- 0.263u, 0.261u and 0.263u (with `putchar_unlocked`).

If I use terminal output I have:

- 8.153u with `printf`,
- 3.862u with `putchar`,
- 0.634u with `putchar_unlocked`.

Elapsed times are:

- 0:09.46 with `printf`,
- 0:07.75 with `putchar`,
- 0:05.06 with `putchar_unlocked`.

-Edit----single *write*---------

You can also *group* everything into a single string and use `puts`, like this:

```
 char baseString[MAX_Y*(MAX_X+2)+1];
 int p = 0;
 for (int y = 0; y < MAX_Y ; y++) 
   {
     baseString[p++] = '\t';
     for (int x = 0; x < MAX_X; x++)
       {
         baseString[p++] = base[y][x];  
       }
     baseString[p++] = '\n';
   }
 baseString[p] = 0;
 puts(baseString); // or fwrite(baseString,p,1,stdout);
```

In that case, test gives:

- 0.448u, 1.155s and 0:04.99 (puts)
- 0.418u, 1.077s, 0:04.81 (fwrite)

This is slightly better than `putchar_unlocked`.

All test made on OSX 10.9, Intel Core i7 2.3Ghz.

Comment: Did you measure the speed gain?

Comment: On my machine `printf` version is roughly slower by a factor 2. `printf` must at least decode two arguments, detect end of string, test for % in format string; so necessary slower.

Comment: Is that user time ("u")? If yes, how does real time change, if any? Your times are fast, are you on a native linux? Are there any changes when you redirect to /dev/null (which makes it 10x faster on cygwin)?

Comment: I tested redirecting all to `/dev/null` not to measure device I/O. I am going to give you terminal output times...

Comment: Oh. Well, I suggest you don't use 100000 then.

Comment: Well, I assume the OP was interested in real terminal output time. We got the "terminal" part ;-). What about "real"? My user time is 0.5s for 10k, but 2.0s real. Of course cygwin may play a role there. DOS as I said is 10x slower for the command window but faster than cygwin when redirecting to NUL, probably indicating cygwin overhead with pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
fwrite(base[y], MAX_X, 1, stdout)
```

to write one whole row at a time

no I havent tested it for speed

Comment: fwrite doesn't writes in a txt file ?